# Absolute value of field isomorphism

Tags: field-theory

I first saw this problem about $2$ years ago. It was given a couple of years ago in a contest that I was preparing for. The original problem statement, not in english, can be seen here:https://www.concursulvaleriualaci.upt.ro/component/jdownloads/send/24-subiecte-faza-finala-2019/161-cls-xii-mi-etapa-finala-2019

Let $K=\{M(z, u) = zI_2 + uA | z, u \in \mathbb{R}\}$, where $I_2$ is the $2\times2$ identity matrix and $A=\begin{pmatrix}0 & -5 \\ 1 & 3\end{pmatrix}$. $K$ forms a field with some unspecified operations $+$ and $\cdot$. At first I assumed these were the usual matrix multiplication and addition, even though the problem doesn't mention it, however that doesn't seem to fit because $K$ wouldn't be closed under multiplication, unless I'm missing something.

$f:(K, +, \cdot) \to (\mathbb{C}, +, \cdot)$ is an isomorphism from the field mentioned above to the complex field. We known that $f(aM)=af(M)$ for any $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $M\in{K}$. The problem asks for the absolute value of $f(M(z, u))$.

$f(M(z, u))=f(zI_2+uA)=f(zI_2)+f(uA)$ because $f$ is a morphism and $zI_2$ and $uA$ are in $K$. By the given property, this equals $zf(I_2)+uf(A)$.

This is about as far as I could get back then, and I can't seem to make much progress now either. I tried to raise $A$ to some powers to see if something interesting happens, but that didn't work. The problem is a bit confusing since $+$ and $\cdot$ seem to be used with different meanings. Can anyone help clarify this? Thanks!

Comment: $K$ is actually closed under multiplication since $A^2=-5I_2+3A$. (Generally speaking, this works for any $2$-by-$2$ matrix thanks to Cayley-Hamilton.)

Comment: Captain Lama's comment also gives you the way: $f(A)=z$ must be a solution of $z^2=-5+3z$.

Comment: I thought of that, but I somehow ended up with $x^2=-5z+3x$ which wasn't quite working. Thanks to both of you! I'll write an answer tomorrow if no one does it in the meantime!